# How to change background slider image when hovering on text?

Tags: images

I'd like to have a full screen slider with several project title headers on top. My goal is that when the user hovers on the name of a project, the backgorund image changes to an image specific to that project (whether that's using the slider or another way). And when the user is not hovered on a project title, the slider just keeps showing its images normally.

I'm guessing that this would involve some JS or CSS, but I'm not sure. I'm relatively new to WordPress.

Comment: Asking for plugin/software recommendations is off topic here, do you already have a slider implemented? Wouldn't this make more sense on stackoverflow? It sounds like a JS/CSS question. Use the edit link to clarify your question further and add missing details.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.